# python modules, call main class in modules

Tags: python, function, module, call

**this is my main module, I can call other module's function with it:**

```
#main.py
from module_1 import module_1

class APP:
    def option(self):
        print("[1]:.....\n[2]:.......")
        option = int(input(":"))
    
        if (option == 1):
            module_1().do_something_1()     #I called module_1
APP().option()
```

**Let's say the user chose the first option, the program will call the function in the module_1**

```
#module_1.py

class module_1:
    def do_something_1(self):
        #.........................
        again = input("Do you wanna start again?")
        if (again == "Y"):
            #what I'm trying to do is here, I want to return the option function again in main.py
        else:
            #................
```

**And user wanted to restart program and Asked question with Y, How can the program return the main.py(APP().option())?**

---

**[UPTADE_1]**

**I actually thought a circular import would work for me here but got an error**

main.py:

```
#main.py
from module_1 import module_1

class APP:
    def option(self):
        print("[1]:.....\n[2]:.......")
        option = int(input(":"))

        if (option == 1):
            module_1().do_something_1()     #I called module_1
APP().option()
```

module_1.py:

```
from main import APP
class module_1:
    def do_something_1(self):
        print(".........")
        again = input("Do you wanna start again?")

        if again=="Y":
            return APP().option()
        else:
            #.......
```

**I get this error**:

```
.............................
from main import APP
ImportError: cannot import name 'APP' from partially initialized module 'main' (most likely due to a circular import)
.............................
```

---

**[UPTADE_2](after [Grismar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64943407/python-modules-call-main-class-in-modules/64960640#64960640))**

main.py:

```
from File import*
class Options:
    def __init__(self):
        #...................
    def ask(self):
        try:
            option=int(input("==>"))
        except Exception as error:
            #......................................
            return Options().ask()

        if option==1:
            File().delete_all_files_extension()
        elif option==2:
            #.........
        elif option==3:
            #.........
        elif option==4:
           #..........
        elif option==5:
            #.........
        elif option==6:
            sys.exit()

Options().ask()
```

Let's say the user chose the first option, the program will call the function in the File

```
import sys
import os
class File:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.deleted_files_number = 0
        self.deleted_files_extension_number = 0
    
    def delete_all_files(self):

        try:
            path = input("[+]Path:")
        except Exception as error:
            print("ERROR:%s"%error)
            #.....................
            #I want to return the option function again in main.py

        try:
            file = open("log[delete_all_files].txt","w")
            if (os.path.exists(path)==True):
                for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
                    for file in f:
                        time.sleep(0.001)
                        print("[*]%s" %os.path.join(r,file))
                        os.remove(os.path.join(r,file))
                        open("log[delete_all_files].txt","a+").write(str(os.path.join(r,file)+"\n"))
                        self.deleted_files_number +=1

                print("[*]Deleted %s file" %self.deleted_files_number)
                again=input("[+]Do you wanna start again?[Y/N]").upper()
                if (again=="Y"):
                    #here it is, the program has to go back to main.py so it can show what can be selected again.
                else:
                    exit()
```

I mean, the program will return if an error or something different occurs within the module, not after the module has finished its work.

Comment: Is the `class module_1` in your second code example an actual `class` or a `module`? You're importing `do_something_1` from `module_1`, but you never import the class. You should be importing it like `from module_1 import module_1.do_something_1`, yes?

Comment: Oh man, that is my fault, I'll fix it

Comment: This isn't Java. You don't need to stick everything in a class. (Heck, even if this *was* Java, you could still use static methods.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, I know this, but I don't want the modules to get mixed up because the program I'm going to do is long.

Comment: Your classes don't help with that in any way. Module-level functions would be clearer.

Comment: @DoğanDündar you're better off learning the conventions of the language instead of forcing the conventions of other languages on it. Why bother to use Python at all, otherwise?

Comment: @Grismar, offer to your information that it is also possible to access classes in different files in python. And this works like this in many applications. Let's say I have collected all classes in a single file. This does not mean that the problem above does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, in `main.py`, you call `APP.option()`. `APP.option()` calls `module_1().do_something_1()`, where `module_1` is a class imported from `module_1`.

You want `module_1().do_something_1` to then call `APP.option()` again (under certain conditions).

A few remarks:

- you would do well to follow Python naming conventions and name `APP` `App`.
- there appears to be little or no utility in wrapping the module `module_1`'s functionality in a class called `module_1`; all this gets you is two completely different entities sharing the same name. If you want to capture the functionality in a class, you should probably name it something that reminds developers using it of its function.
- you're calling `APP().option()`, which means you're instantiating a new object every time, creating a new `APP()` with a new menu every time
- most importantly, since `APP.option()` can call `module_1().do_something_1` indefinitely and `module_1().do_something_1` can call `APP.option()`, you run the risk of creating an application that ends up exhausting the recursion depth.

Object-oriented software design is all about picking the correct scope for your classes,  giving them clear jobs that encapsulate behaviour and data that clearly goes together; to create software that's easier to maintain and extend.

The main function of your `App` class appears to be to present the user with options and execute matching functionality. The main function of `module_1` appears to be to 'do something' and then return to the main loop. You want to present the user with the options again or allow them to exit the app, after 'doing something'.

From a design perspective, it seems to make more sense to have the `App` present the user with the 'start again' question - after all, it has nothing to do with whatever was done in `module_1`. If it does depend on what happens there, it makes sense to have the `do_something_1()` method return a result and base the decision to continue on the returned value.

You could even base that return value on the question you ask the user, although I don't like that design decision:

```
if again=="Y":
    return True
else:
    # ... do something else ...
    return False
```

And in `main.py`:

```
    def option(self):
        again = True
        while again:
            print("[1]:.....\n[2]:.......")
            option = int(input(":"))

            if (option == 1):
                again = module_1().do_something_1()
```

Another solution could be to create the `module_1`, passing the `App` it belongs to as an owner and keeping a reference to it in the object. Something like:

```
def __init__(self, owner):
    self.owner = owner

# ...

        if again=="Y":
            return self.owner.option()
```

That solves the object creation issue, but is still circular of course.

You can have modules importing parts of each other and the correct way to do that would be by adding them to a package. However, you would still have to find a way to get around circular creation of the classes - if `Class1` creates an instance of `Class2`, but
`Class2` creates an instance of `Class1`, you can see where that's going.

What's wrong with something like this:

`main.py`

```
from module_1 import Class_1

class App:
    def menu(self):
        run_menu = True
        while run_menu :
            print("[1]:.....\n[2]:.......")
            option = int(input(":"))

            if (option == 1):
                Class_1().do_something_1()

            print(".........")
            run_menu = input("Do you wanna start again?") == "Y"

App().menu()
```

`module_1.py`

```
class Class_1:
    def do_something_1():
        print('doing something')
        return
```

The problem you're having is more a problem of design, not so much of the language. If you have an example of functionality where you feel the circular import is a requirement, you should probably post a question with that example specifically - but you're likely to be marked a duplicate of one of many questions asking about circular imports.

The short answer is: there's almost always a better solution.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your advice on naming. Returning to the question; There is a bounce while the module I made is running. So, in your last example, after the module has finished its work, the program asks questions to continue, but what I tried to do is, for example, an error occurred while the module was continuing its work, and the module will ask if it should run again. I guess it will be better for me to share a little more of my code.